# how to add map box tiles to gmap?

Tags: c#, user-interface, maps, gmap.net, mbtiles

I want to get map box tiles from database but it does not work. I get MBTilesMapProvider class from [here](https://github.com/geobabbler/MBTilesMapProvider).
It is invoked like below:

```
map.Manager.Mode = AccessMode.ServerAndCache;
map.MapProvider = new  MBTilesMapProvider("C:\\Users\\NPC\\Desktop\\test\\ne.mbtiles");
```

result:
[image: [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGRCP.png]

but if google maps used as map provider like below it works well

```
map.Manager.Mode = AccessMode.ServerAndCache;
map.MapProvider = GoogleSatelliteMapProvider.Instance;
```

When i debuged i noticed that [GetTiles](https://github.com/geobabbler/MBTilesMapProvider/blob/master/Helpers/MBTilesHelper.cs) method is invoked never.

Note: I think there is no problem about finding database because it reads meta data from database.

Comment: GetTiles() returns an image (see : https://github.com/geobabbler/MBTilesMapProvider/blob/master/Helpers/MBTilesHelper.cs).  So in c# you need a picturebox for the image.

Comment: i think it is not the main problem when i debug i noticed that GetTiles is invoked never.

Comment: You need an image so you can set a picturebox : pictureBox1.Image.  What are you getting know?  A byte array or a stream?  You need to convert what you have to an image.

Comment: i think gmap.net handles it automatically as i don't invoke GetTiles method explicitly. However, The real problem is mapbox tiles' x and y (row and column) are different than gmap tiles, as i understand.

Comment: Somehow gmap started to admit it cannot find files, even though i have not changed anything.

Comment: Here is Microsoft documentation.  The Provider is a webcontrol with each tile a different html document : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/data-access/database-driven-site-maps/building-a-custom-database-driven-site-map-provider-cs

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved solution by make a bit changes at MBTilesHelper.cs.

First i realized that when reading metadata from database MinZoom and MaxZoom values, they always stay as zero because it does not contain MinZoom or MaxZoom. Therefore, i set them manually.

and secondly i changed a bit "getImage" method.

```
private PureImage getImage(GPoint pos, int zoom)
{
    PureImage retval = null;

    var resultImage = _mbtiles.GetTileStream(pos.X, pos.Y, zoom);
        
    if (resultImage != null && resultImage.Length > 0)
    {
        //resultImage.Position = 0L;
        retval = GetTileImageFromArray(resultImage);
    }
    return retval;
}
```